# R & Lubridate: how to set time zone when importing csv file

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse, lubridate

I'm trying to import a csv file as an R dataframe where one of the columns is a string representing a date-time. I can't get the time zone component to set correctly.

This code works when I don't explicitly set the time zone:

```
example2 <- read_csv("NAME, TRNSCO, ID, DPMNEM, DATE, PEAK
                 BEC,EGSI,1062,SERP,10/12/2022 18:00,6.464
                 BEC,EGSI,1072,SPTR,10/30/2022 22:00,67.456
                 BEC,EGSI,1152,DYNE,10/24/2022 12:00,4.606
                 CLA,ELI,3023,FRMR,10/12/2022 17:00,6.352
                 CLA,ELI,3043,SHON,10/19/2022 8:00,2.296
                 CLA,ELI,3063,BERN,10/20/2022 7:00,5.232",
            col_types = cols_only(
              NAME = col_character(),
              ID =  col_character(),
              DPMNEM = col_character(),
              DATE = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),
              PEAK = col_double()))
```

And this code works:

```
parse_datetime("10/12/2022 18:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",
           locale = locale(tz = "US/Central"))
```

But fails when I try to put it all together:

```
example3 <- read_csv("NAME, TRNSCO, ID, DPMNEM, DATE, PEAK
                 BEC,EGSI,1062,SERP,10/12/2022 18:00,6.464
                  BEC,EGSI,1072,SPTR,10/30/2022 22:00,67.456
                 BEC,EGSI,1152,DYNE,10/24/2022 12:00,4.606
                 CLA,ELI,3023,FRMR,10/12/2022 17:00,6.352
                 CLA,ELI,3043,SHON,10/19/2022 8:00,2.296
                 CLA,ELI,3063,BERN,10/20/2022 7:00,5.232",
                 col_types = cols_only(
                   NAME = col_character(),
                   ID =  col_character(),
                   DPMNEM = col_character(),
                   DATE = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", locale = locale(tz = "US/Central")),
                   PEAK = col_double()))
```

I get this error message:

Error in col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", locale = locale(tz = "US/Central")) :
unused argument (locale = locale(tz = "US/Central"))

I've tried variations of the tz parameter with no luck, e.g.:

```
DATE = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "US/Central"),
```

Also, how can I extract the tz component from datetime datetime column?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is already an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/1122) in github.  It is closed as not possible

Comment: `example[["DATE"]] <- example[["DATE"]] |> strptime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "US/Central") |> as.POSIXct()` should do the trick with `DATE = col_character()` when using `read_csv()` instead of `DATE = col_datetime()`.

Comment: @akrun: thanks, did not see this in my search before I asked.

Comment: @dmflk: thanks this code worked and solved my problem.